# Unable to send html mail with an attachment

Tags: php, email

**Php code used:**

```
    $boundary = uniqid("np");

    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" ;
    $header .= "From: $from\r\n";
    $header .= "To: $to\r\n";
    if (!is_null($reply_to)) $header .= "Reply-To: $reply_to \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";

    //here is the content body
    $message = "This is a multi part message in MIME format.\n\n";

    $message .= "--" . $boundary . "\n";
    $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n";

    $message .= "Hello, <BR> This is a text email, the <bold>html version</bold>.";
    $message .= "<BR>Regards";
    $message .= "<BR>Your Name";
    $message .= "\n\n--" . $boundary . "\n";

    $file_name = "file_01.txt";
    $file_content = "Ciao - file 1";
    $chunked_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content));  

    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$file_name\"\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\n"; 
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\\n" . $chunked_content . "\n\n";  
    $message .= "--{$boundary}--";
```

**Results:** HTML Mail IS OK, there is the attached file with right filename but it's empty

**What's wrong ?**

Edit: ! tried to replace every \n with \r\n but the results is an empty mail..

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a simple and hard attachment (just curious)?

Comment: I removed the word 'simple'.. is simple because is a plain txt

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: I've maniacal error-reporting level, but no errors/warnings.

Comment: Your boundary needs a newline at the end before the `$file_name` var

Comment: Also I think `--{$boundary}--` should be used at the very end, use `--{$boundary}` to mark the different content types.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge: I edited to change as you suggested: now email html body is ok, attachment is in email but it's empty

Comment: @WilliamGeorge: sorry, the problem was an extra '\' before an '\n' in 
penultimate row

Comment: Aha, glad you spotted it. I too can see that now :)

Comment: Im just curious. But why not use PHPMailer or some similar 3rd party class for composing mails, why reinvent the wheel everytime you send a mail with attachments?

Comment: just because i've not done the webapp on which i'm working so I must fix but I cannot change ... it's a dirty world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code for email attachments. Try this

```
function mailWithAttachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message)
{
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\n\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $header .= $message."\n\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\n\n";
    $header .= $content."\n\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if(mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just return mail($mailto... since mail returns a boolean

Comment: Do you send everything in header, with empty body !?

Comment: yes we are using this for attachment ly mails ... so we dont use body text

Comment: This works, but email body is empty. I also need plain AND html body, can you help me editing your code?

Comment: @Purefan, you are right, I use to do other code stuff inside those blocks in my projects, so we are using such. Though I may have removed that before posting, any ways thanks

Comment: @realtebo try passing the data to `$message` parameter in the function. For this mailer you need to add all the html content in the header section itself which is taken care by `$message` .